# create editing modal in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

i'm trying to make a timesheet table that takes inputs from attendance machine, and it can be edited later on, my table look like this:

![timesheet table][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D1ap.png

this is the popup to edit time and reason of editing the half day :

[edit time and reason][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPa37.png

however, when i pick time and reason, i can't update them in the table, this is the code of modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="change-date" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change-dateLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="change-dateLabel">Changer l'heure</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="motif" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">MCD</option>
                            <option value="">MTA</option>
                            <option value="">CA</option>
                            <option value="">AIR</option>
                            <option value="">MLD</option>
                            <option value="">CS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there any solution to make it working?

Comment: it's not going to magically happen you need some js or PHP code, can you show us some?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you need a couple of things for your modal form to work.

1. You need to add route in your form open tag (see my example below)
2. Your form submit button at the modal-footer div needs to be inside the form open and close tags (see my exaple below)
3. Your submit button must have a type of submit for it to send to form parameters. (see my example below)
4. You need a method in your controller to process your form request and save into the database (Hope you know that.).

   ```
    <div class="modal fade" id="change-date" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change-dateLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{ Form::open(['action' => 'YourController@update_method','method' =>'PATCH']) }}
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="change-dateLabel">Changer l'heure</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{-- <form action=""> remove --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="motif" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">MCD</option>
                            <option value="">MTA</option>
                            <option value="">CA</option>
                            <option value="">AIR</option>
                            <option value="">MLD</option>
                            <option value="">CS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                {{-- </form> remove --}}
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                    {{-- Your submit button should look like this --}}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
                </div>
                {{ Form::close() }} <!-- end form -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   ```

Also make sure the function you put on your form's action attribute is defined on your routes file like this below

```
Route::patch('url', 'YourController@update_method')->name('model.update_method');.
```